# how do I get OSX Git CLI to play nice with GitHub?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I just installed Git on OSX 10.8.2 and I'm trying to learn how to use it.

I installed Git (git-1.8.1.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg) and GitHub for OSX (which looks like a nice GUI for Git). I also installed Git CLI. But the local repositories I am adding, initing, and committing using the CLI are not showing up in GitHub for OSX.

How can I make them sync up?

Using the CLI, cd'd into a folder with a bunch of text files, then did:

```
    git init
    git add *
    git commit -m "added new files"
```

But in my GitHub for OSX client, even after I refresh, I don't see my new local repository.

I'm not pushing to a remote GitHub repository, only using local repositories.

I checked out my ~/.gitconfig file, and the username and e-mail address there seem to match the one I entered in the GitHub for OSX Preferences/login.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Github has a bunch of documentation on how to use the cli with their site and repositories, most of which can be found at: https://help.github.com/

Comment: Yeah I followed the instructions here - https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git - didn't work, my repositories aren't showing up.

Comment: If you want them to show up in the OSX GUI, you'll need to set the directory there/run its scan function.

Comment: OK, I went to the parent directory, did a git init, git add, git commit, but the repository still doesn't show up in GitHub. How do I "set" and "scan"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub for Mac client will only automatically show repositories pushed to GitHub.com. For repositories which are "local" only, you need to drag/drop the folder from Finder into GitHub for Mac, as mentioned here: http://mac.github.com/help.html#faq-add-repositories